# ionic 2 Sidemenu does not toggle on swiping on screen

Tags: ionic2

In ionic2 today I start with template sidemenu and side menu is toggle on swiping on screen from every where by mouse. That means when swip from left to right on screen side menu is opening and from right to left sidemenu is close properly.
But when i buid this on my phone ITS NOT WORKING. Today almost all application has this facilities and no one go to top to touch menu button on left-top corrner to open side menu. how can enable this features I also try with making

TO 

but does'nt Work

thanx in advance

Comment: Some correction.. I also try with making ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" TO ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="true" but does'nt Work

Comment: It should work by the way.